# How to create arrays with jquery and alter session?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, playlist

How to create arrays with jquery and alter session?

I want to store in $ _SESSION ["playlist"] a list of songs with titles, urls mp3 and authors

This is an example of my html code

```
    <a class="add-music" data-title="Title of the little song" data-artist="artist1" href="audios/song-little.mp3">Add to List</a>
    <a class="download-music" href="audios/song-little.mp3">Download</a>


    <a class="add-music" data-title="Title of middle song" data-artist="artist2" href="audios/song-middle.mp3">Add to List</a>
    <a class="download-music" href="audios/song-middle.mp3">Download</a>


    <a class="add-music" data-title="Title of big song" data-artist="artist3" href="audios/song-big.mp3">Add to List</a>
    <a class="download-music" href="audios/song-big.mp3">Download</a>
```

and my jquery is so

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.add-music').click(
function() {
  var songNew=new Array ({
    title: $(this).attr('data-title'),

    artist: $(this).attr('data-artist'),
    mp3: $(this).attr('href')
  });
});
});
```

I want to know how to store in session several songs with their titles, authors and url of mp3

I read that with json, I can make each song set of values ​​for a string, and an array with several strings, this array save session

thanks for any help

Comment: what does jQuery have to do with session? `$ _SESSION` is on server, jQuery is in browser. Need far more details to understand what you are trying to accomplish. As it stands right now, question makes little sense

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to send arrays through ajax to server and then save it in session.

If you don't know how to send you can use javascript object notation.

```
var data={title:"sometitle",song:"song"}
```

you can even use nested javascript object notation to use it like arrays.

and then you can use this in $.ajax call using post. you can retrieve these values in php
by using $_POST['title']; and $_POST['song'];

Comment: with your idea improve my light, and I will work with php to modify the session

had this right now, which amends after reading your comment

 `$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.add-music').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        'type':'POST',
        'data':fuction() {
          var songNew = JSON.stringify({
            title: $(this).attr('data-title'),
            artist: $(this).attr('data-artist'),
            mp3: $(this).attr('href'),
          });
        });
        datatype: 'json',
        url: 'sess.php',
        async: true,
        cache:false
        });
    });
 });`